# how to do If button is pressed, a hardcoded message as an output into label

Tags: objective-c

How do I write a command as if a button is pressed there will be a specific sentence as an output to a label on an app.

Comment: using button action

Comment: please can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
-(IBAction)yourAction:(id)sender
{
    yourLabel.text = @"Button Pressed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Proper Controller Code Required

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *mylabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *myButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mylabel,myButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mylabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height*0.11, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    mylabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false;
    [mylabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    mylabel.text = @"Button Not Pressed";
    [self.view addSubview:mylabel];

    myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height*0.13, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false;
    [myButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];


}

-(void) buttonHandler:(UIButton*)sender{
    mylabel.text = @"ButtonPressed";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

**Before Pressing button**

[image]

**After Pressing Button**

[image]